# how to create new elements with diff-diff tags like a tag p tag etc

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create some new elements with javascript like when I click on an `Anchor` tag it should create a new `Anchor` tag and if I click on `h1` tag it should create an `h1` tag ...

This is my code that I have done:

```html
    <html>
      <body>
        <button type="button" id="aTag" onclick="createA()">a tag</button>
        <button type="button" id="pTag">p tag</button>
        <button type="button">h1 tag</button>
        <button type="button">h4 tag</button>
        <script>
            function createA() {
              var a = document.createElement('a');
              a.text = "hello";
              document.getElementById('aTag').append(a);
            }
        </script>
      </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Answered Check it if work well then consider green tick

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by this,

```js
function myFunction() {
  var node = document.createElement("a");
  node.innerHTML="Hi New Link";
  node.setAttribute("href","https://www.youtube.com");
  document.getElementById("result").appendChild(node);
}
function myFunctionh1() {
  var node = document.createElement("h1");
  node.innerHTML="Hi, New H1";
  document.getElementById("result").appendChild(node);
}
```

```html
<a onclick="myFunction()">A Click Me</a>

<div id="result"></div>

<h1 onclick="myFunctionh1()">H1 click me</h1>
```